# Accessing Property of a method from another method inside a class in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to Access the property "na" of "ha" public method from "test" method in same class. But I am getting error "Trying to get property 'ni' of non-object"

```
 public function ha(){
        $ni =  'fs';
        $nin = 'adfsfsfs';

    }

    public function test()
    {
       echo $this->ha()->ni;
    }
```

Comment: Your function doesn't have a `return` statement, so `$this->ha()` is `null`, and `null->ni` is not valid... You could do `return (object)['ni' => 'fs', 'nin' => 'adfsfsfs'];`, and it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Variables inside a method are only available inside that method. You should either define on your class or return the values from the method and call the method to get the values. Also please note that this is not about laravel, but it's about php. For more information about variable scope: [check this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)